# Tab Bar Icons won't show

Tags: iphone, tabs, icons

So,here's my problem.
When i try to put icons into resources and then select them into IB,once i load the Simulator that icons don't show up. I tried to clean the project up, but nothing.. It may be the fact that i have "home.png" and "home@2x.png" optimized for retina screen,and it can't recognize the right one? It's also happened again,but i solved with this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] drawAsPatternInRect:rect];
```

}

But here? Is there a code for the Tab bar too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by making 30x30 high quality icons, so that both standard and retina can read and show them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the target checkbox is not checked for these images

http://illogic-al.org/images/screenshots/Xcode_target.png

This checkbox should be checked to copy resources when installing on device/simulator, so when an image is not checked, il will not be copied and will not appear

Comment: @Phillip, when you added the files to resources, there was a small box that you could check to copy the files. That may also be a relevant box to check.

Comment: If you are using Xcode 3, it will be just under the search bar (after you select the file).
For Xcode 4, you should select file, then show Utilities View (button at top right), then you can find "target membership" tab with the checkbox

Comment: @PengOne: Copy items into destination's group folder? It's already checked,if it's that one

Comment: Ok, so it may be another think.
Hev you checked that the image names are correct (no case difference). the images appear in IB and don't appear in simulator, right?

Comment: Yep, even if in IB you can choose directly from there the images from  the resources.. IB shows them properly, simulator \ ipod nope

Comment: Have you followed apple guidelines (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8 ) :

Use pure white with appropriate alpha transparency.
Do not include a drop shadow.
Use anti-aliasing.
...

Comment: I found on the internet the icon i found. so i can't tell exactly how are they made.. But i'll read and i'll see 
EDIT: 
i deleted the @2x references and now it shows up correctly. So i have to understand why @2x images aren't show up..